# In selenium how can I preform different actions in different links at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium

I have looked in so many places and either I'm not searching for the right keywords or I'm doing something thats rare or not possible.

So in my app I have a function that grabs multiple links across the website, now I want to then open all of these links and preform actions on them, at the same time.

I do not have access to the code as of right now but it goes something like this:

```
bar = driver.get_elements_by_class_name('class_name')

for foo in bar:
    link = foo.get_element_by_xpath('.xpath').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```

Now that outputs 10 or so links that I now want to open and perform actions on individually, at the same time. What can I do?

Comment: The only option i can think of is to initialize 10 instances of whatever driver you are using... it would take some python fanciness, I think, to make sure the actions happen simultaneously (why is that important, by the way)? I can try to come up with a good example if you are interested in pursuing this technique.

Comment: This is a unrealistic scenario, asked without showing the intended code towards the problem

Comment: @C. Peck im trying to scrap some information about colleges on a website that provides that information for each college in my state. There is no exact need to make it simultaneous but i thought i would be not only cooler but faster, especially trying to access 10+ websites.

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: @DMart to gather intuition prices, ratings, etc... from each website. I just want to do it in parallel so its faster.

Comment: Just kick off your program 10 different times targeting 10 different websites?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the driver can only run one task at once, so you have to do it inside your URLs loop. Or you may also search for `multiple threads` with python, and that's a little bit advanced.

Comment: MultiThreading is not a good option for selenium, webdriver is not thread-safe. Unfortunately the maintainers have never addressed this issue, admittedly it would be a complex undertaking.